# PHP - If I know the session_id, how to get session variables

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have a PHP site but a portion uses a flash upload swf to post a file and some parameters to a PHP script.

When that swf posts parameters my PHP script doesn't know any of the session variables.  Must be something funky with Flash and the cookies it sends.

Anyways, I could try to fix it in flash but I thought the easier way is to simply pass the `session_id` in a post parameter.  However, once I receive this `session_id` in my PHP script, I don't know how to use it to lookup the session variables I really want (such as `$_SESSION['username']`).  I don't want to pass `$_SESSION['username']` as a POST parameter because I figure that would be too much of a security risk.  A long random `session_id` seems much better.

Comment: Share some code please. Are you using `session_start()` on top of all files where you either want to read or write session values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [session_id()](http://php.net/session_id):

> `string session_id ([ string $id ] )`
>  session_id() is used to get
>   **or set** the session id for the current session.

Code in vanilla PHP would roughly look like this:

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['session_id']) ){
    session_id($_POST['session_id']);
    session_start();
}
```

Not sure though whether it'll be easy to integrate with CakePHP.